# Error with casting

Tags: sql-server-2008, casting, varchar

I have a query where I have to extract some number fields from varchar column.
When i do some replace and substring in select statement and cast it to bigint everything works fine, but when I use this same cast in join it throws error
'Error converting data type varchar to bigint'.
How is this possible?

```
select CAST(
        case when CHARINDEX('/',f.BML,1)>0 
            then substring(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(f.BML,'A',''),'B',''),'C',''),'+',''),',',''),'S',''),'H',''),'P',''),'¸','') ,1,CHARINDEX('/',BML,1)-1)
        else replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(f.BML,'A',''),'B',''),'C',''),'+',''),',',''),'S',''),'H',''),'P',''),'¸','') 
        end as bigint)
from TableN n join TableO o  on
    n.Id=o.Id 
    join TableF f on
        f.OId=o.OId and
        substring(cast(n.RJ as varchar(10)),1,3)=substring(CAST(f.MT AS varchar(10)),1,3) and
    CAST(
        case when CHARINDEX('/',f.BML,1)>0 then substring(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(f.BML,'A',''),'B',''),'C',''),'+',''),',',''),'S',''),'H',''),'P',''),'¸','') ,1,CHARINDEX('/',f.BML,1)-1)
        else replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(f.BML,'A',''),'B',''),'C',''),'+',''),',',''),'S',''),'H',''),'P',''),'¸','') 
        end as bigint) =n.mbr
order by n.Ident
```

Comment: I would guess that you have values in your `varchar` column that can not be converted to `bigint`.

Comment: @Mikael Eriksson But how can that same cast pass in select statement?
It should throw same exception.

Comment: Do you have a where clause that is filtering out the row(s) causing the error?

Comment: The join will probably have a look at all rows in the table. When used in a field list chances are that the conversion is applied only to the rows actually returned.

Comment: We can't see your query - but be aware that there are few, if any, guarantees on the order in which conditions are checked in SQL - so if you have conditions like `WHERE Column LIKE '[0-9]' and CONVERT(bigint,Column) = 5`, it may choke on the conversion.

Comment: I've added original code to my post.
I only modified table and column names.
When I comment cast in join everything works fine.
As you can see I use same cast in select and join.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I indicated in my comment, there's no guarantee on the order in which conditions are assessed. So if you have:

```
    f.OId=o.OId and
    substring(cast(n.RJ as varchar(10)),1,3)=substring(CAST(f.MT AS varchar(10)),1,3) and
CAST(
    case when CHARINDEX('/',f.BML,1)>0 then substring(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(f.BML,'A',''),'B',''),'C',''),'+',''),',',''),'S',''),'H',''),'P',''),'¸','') ,1,CHARINDEX('/',f.BML,1)-1)
    else replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(f.BML,'A',''),'B',''),'C',''),'+',''),',',''),'S',''),'H',''),'P',''),'¸','') 
    end as bigint) =n.mbr
```

And either `f.OId=o.OId` or `substring(cast(n.RJ as varchar(10)),1,3)=substring(CAST(f.MT AS varchar(10)),1,3)` should eliminate rows with values of `BML` that are not convertible to `bigint`, that's no guarantee that the conversion will not be attempted.

---

You can attempt to move the filters that should eliminate bad `BML` values into a subquery or CTE, but that's still no guarantee that the query optimizer won't push the conversion operator down into the subquery and still cause an error.

The only real way to deal with this (unfortunately) is to split the query into two pieces, eliminating unconvertible values in the first query, and placing the result of this query in a temp table/table variable. Then build the second half of the query using this temp table.

Comment: I thought about moving to temp table, but that will further complicate query. This is one time query which I need to find duplicate data.
Well, i suppose there is no other way. 
Thank you anyway Damien.